# PHP optimization case : concat vs template

Tags: php, optimization

I had small question about optimization. Consider two following cases :

```
$assignment = null;
for ($i = 0; $i< 10000; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++){
                $assignment .= " ${j} ${i}";
        }
}
```

And

```
$assignment = null;
for ($i = 0; $i< 10000; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 20; $j++){
                $assignment = "${assignment} ${j} ${i}";
        }
}
```

Execution time of first script is about 0.25 sec, Second : 15sec
Why there's a big difference between them?

Comment: `.=` is a string concatenation which makes it O(n^2) meaning a new string is entirely generated from the current one.

Comment: I believe this question is off topic here. The code works, it only takes a long time to finish

Comment: @Bablo What are you doing with `$assignment` afterwards? Are you printing it somewhere or is it just a question of curiosity?

Comment: @vivek_23 only curiosity.

Comment: @Bablo Second approach actually does string parsing in a complex way in terms of templating as it is used to evaluate complex expressions. [See here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) I suspect PHP would do a pre-processing to analyze how to parse the string and fall into the complex category taking more time to execute than the first one.

Comment: I would argue that this type of optimization is very much moot today. Both PHP and servers are so fast that this would most likely be the least of any performance issues you run into.

Comment: The first example does a simple concatenation, the second an assignment. So both functions are doing kinda different things. As the string grows it needs to reserve new memory with a larger size for each iteration.